# Accessing Laravel URL::Route from Custom Class

Tags: php, laravel

I have begun implementing the Model-View-Presenter pattern in my Laravel application and I am running into the issue of not being able to access the URL::route service from my presenter class. I have created a "presenters" directory in the app directory.

Here is the code for my presenter class:

```
namespace Presenter;

class ViewListingPresenter implements Presenter
{
    public function present($response)
    {
        $model = new ViewListingModel();

        ...

        $model->editButtonURL = URL::route('listings.edit', $response->id);


        ...

        return View::make('listings.show', compact('model'));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Presenter\URL' not found
```

In the controller and view class I am able to use services such as Route::method or URL::method, but how do I access these from a custom class in a custom directory? What namespace or class do I need to include to be able to access this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently in a namespace but are trying to use a class outside of it. As `URL` is not using any namespace you can add `use URL;` below your `namespace Presenter;` row.

Answer (score 0):

Your class uses `Presenter` namespace while `URL` belongs to the root namespace. So you have two options:

A. Before declaring your class add:

```
use URL;
```

and inside your class call:

```
URL::route();
```

B. Just inside your class call:

```
\URL::route();
```

and you are done!